# Trying to write hello world using eclipse as application but nothing gets displayed in console

Tags: php

I'm trying to get started in php and use the hello worl
I'm using elcipse Marse 2
When I run the program I see a flash in the console screen, but 
the text hello world does not shown.
The top of the console window shows the location of the php.exe
This is what I did

- 1. Created a new project
- 2. Add a new php file called hello world
- 3. typed in echo "hello world world";
- 4. the source now looks like

> ```
> <?php
>     echo"hellow world";
> ?>
> ```

- 5. select run from run menu
- 6. dialog comes up select run as application
- 7. the console window flashes but I dont see hellow world

Comment: PHP doesn't work local unless on xamp sir.

Comment: @clearshot66 that code should run real nice in the PHP CLI so in this case no actual web server would be needed

Comment: Config the project as a PHP CLI and then output should appear in an Eclipse window/panel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had to edit php.ini file, it was turn off